# Checkbox carregado do banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um dificuldade na execução de uma lógica, eu tenho um tabela no banco que salva os valores de um array, pega os valores de um ou mais checkbox selecionados e salva com # separando os numeros.
Ex: 0#1#2#3#4#5#6#.
Quero retornar esse valor do banco e falar que aquele chekbox que tenha algum desses valores fique marcado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tenta algo assim:

```
//array o valor de todos inputs
$todos_itens = array(
'1' => 'Valor 1',
'2' => 'Valor 2',
'3' => 'Valor 3',
'4' => 'Valor 4',
'5' => 'Valor 5',
'6' => 'Valor 6',
'7' => 'Valor 7',
'8' => 'Valor 8',
'9' => 'Valor 9',
'10' => 'Valor 10'
);

//retorno do banco
$retorno_banco = '0#1#3#4#6';

//transforma o retorno em um array
$itens = explode('#',$retorno_banco);
foreach ($itens as $value) {
  $marcado[$value] = true;
}

//percorre todos os inputs verificando se existe o array $marcado
foreach ($todos_itens as $numero => $input) {
if($marcado[$numero]){
  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked name="input" value="'.$numero.'">'.$input;
}else{
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="input" value="'.$numero.'">'.$input;
}
echo '<hr>';
}
```

Ficou assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente, salvou minha vida. Obrigado!